# How to Hijack/change the Header Request Payload in Developer tools of chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, selenium, katalon-studio

I am testing an angular 2 application in which problem is automation script picking up a virtual DOM attribute and because of which a dependent drop down list is not getting populated through katalon automation script(Note doing manual test execution dependent drown list is getting populated only issue when trying with automation).

Is there a way in Katalon that i can hijack or change the DOM element using Jquery so that automation able to send correct attribute value to Request payload of header.

Attached is header request payload (highlighted in yellow) which i wish to hijack or change while automation test execution.
[image]

Comment: What do you exactly mean by `hijack`? Can you brief about the manual steps you are trying to Automate?

Comment: Am testing angular 2 simple web application where my automation script get data from excel and inserting into angular application like employee number,but somehow browser changing that employee to a hardcoded value of -1 but  when i am doing this step manually like inserting employee 20234 (for example), browser DOM is sending  employee as 20234 which is expected .This is the reason i like to change or hijack  this DOM employee attribute in katalon script so that it sends employee which is i am providing using excel and not hardcoded value